# Why LibGDX sound pitch doesn't work with GWT?

Tags: gwt, libgdx, game-development

I use the instance of class Sound. To get the desired pitch I use the method:

```
public long loop (float volume, float pitch, float pan);
```

It works as expected on desktop build but on GWT pitch isn't working.

My gwtVersion is `2.8.2`, gdxVersion is `1.9.10` and I use `de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6`.

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now and would be very thankful for any input.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "isn't working"? Error messages, expected vs actual behavior, code you tried, etc?

Comment: The sound is produced but pitch doesn't work. Different values of pitch produce the same sound. I also tried setPitch method on Sound instance but result is the same. I don't have these problems on desktop build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Why LibGDX sound pitch doesn't work with GWT?"

Because the official libGDX GWT backend uses SoundManager for playing sounds within the browser, and SoundManager does not support pitching.

To get it run, you must change to another solution: the WebAudio API. Lucky as you are, others already implemented it for libGDX, but it is not pulled into the repository for unknown reasons. See [PR 5659](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/5659).

As told in the PR, you can switch to my forked GWT backend to get it to work. Simply change your gradle.build file

```
implementation 'com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-backends:gdx-backend-gwt:1.910.0'
```

You also need to declare the Jitpack repo if you don't already have.

Comment: Thank you very much for the push in right direction. I just need some more info how to modify my build.gradle file. I changed compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion" to compile 'com.github.MrStahlfelge.gdx-backends:gdx-backend-gwt:1.910.0'. I did these changes in project(":html"). I am not very knowledgeable about gradle. Can you please specify exactly what I have to change in build.gradle.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You can find the full information [on the repo's readme file](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-backends)